# Angular + Jest: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?)

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, angular8, monorepo

I am operating inside a Typescript Monorepo. I want to add an Angular 8 frontend with Jest testing to the Monorepo. But I am encountering some issues.

I am using

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.5
```

## What I did

> I will use [this repository](https://github.com/flolude/stackoverflow-monorepo-angular-jest/tree/5e6b316b3be5f02a596735eeeb48e6c18dca10a2) as a starting point!

### 1. Create Angular Application

Then in `<root>/services` I ran:

```
ng new frontend
```

After the Angular application was created I was able to run `ng test` with the following result:

[image: ng test default]

Everything works fine.

### 2. Add Jest

> I am using https://github.com/briebug/jest-schematic to easily add Jest to my Angular application

```
yarn global add @briebug/jest-schematic
ng add @briebug/jest-schematic
```

This results in the following changes

[image: changes]

Running `jest` results in the following error:

```
$ jest
 FAIL  src/app/app.component.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    File not found: <rootDir>/src/tsconfig.spec.json (resolved as: /home/flo/Desktop/stackoverflow-monorepo-angular-jest/services/frontend/src/tsconfig.spec.json)

      at ConfigSet.resolvePath (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:712:19)
      at ConfigSet.get (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:202:67)
      at ConfigSet.tsJest (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/util/memoize.js:43:24)
      at ConfigSet.get (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:297:41)
      at ConfigSet.versions (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/util/memoize.js:43:24)
      at ConfigSet.get (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:583:32)
      at ConfigSet.jsonValue (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/util/memoize.js:43:24)
      at ConfigSet.get [as cacheKey] (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:598:25)
      at TsJestTransformer.getCacheKey (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/ts-jest-transformer.js:126:36)
      at ScriptTransformer._getCacheKey (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:266:23)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.267s
Ran all test suites.
```

### 3. Fixing Errors

Jest tries to find the `tsconfig.spec.json` in the wrong folder. Fortunately, I found [a fix](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/286#issuecomment-519050423). I needed to change the `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setup-jest.ts'],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsConfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      diagnostics: false,
      stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.html$',
      astTransformers: [require.resolve('jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer')],
    },
  },
};
```

Now when I run `jest` it works:

[image: jest pass default]

### 4. My Issue

I've now added the Angular `HttClient` to my `AppComponent`:

```js
// app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'frontend';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

I've also added the `HttpClientModule` to `app.module.ts` and to the `imports` in the `app.component.spec.ts`.

```js
// app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
// app.component.spec.ts

import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'frontend'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('frontend');
  });

  it('should render title', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.content span').textContent).toContain('frontend app is running!');
  });
});
```

However, when running `jest`, I get the following errors:

```
$ jest
 FAIL  src/app/app.component.spec.ts
  AppComponent
    ✕ should create the app (449ms)
    ✕ should have as title 'frontend' (10ms)
    ✕ should render title (10ms)

  ● AppComponent › should create the app

    Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).

      at syntaxError (../../../packages/compiler/src/util.ts:100:17)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:957:27)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:836:20)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:377:18)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:224:11)
      at ../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:135:36
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at ../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:133:65
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at JitCompiler._loadModules (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:130:71)
      at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:115:32)
      at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:69:33)
      at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../../../packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/compiler_factory.ts:69:27)
      at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../../../../packages/platform-browser-dynamic/testing/src/compiler_factory.ts:57:27)
      at TestBedViewEngine.compileComponents (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:362:27)
      at Function.TestBedViewEngine.compileComponents (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:160:66)
      at testing_1.async (src/app/app.component.spec.ts:11:8)

  ● AppComponent › should create the app

    Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).

      at syntaxError (../../../packages/compiler/src/util.ts:100:17)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:957:27)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:836:20)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:377:18)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:224:11)
      at ../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:135:36
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at ../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:133:65
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at JitCompiler._loadModules (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:130:71)
      at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:115:32)
      at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:65:38)
      at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (../../../packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/compiler_factory.ts:61:35)
      at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (../../../../packages/platform-browser-dynamic/testing/src/compiler_factory.ts:52:27)
      at TestBedViewEngine._initIfNeeded (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:376:28)
      at TestBedViewEngine.createComponent (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:570:10)
      at Function.TestBedViewEngine.createComponent (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:232:36)
      at it (src/app/app.component.spec.ts:15:29)

  ● AppComponent › should have as title 'frontend'

    Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).

      at syntaxError (../../../packages/compiler/src/util.ts:100:17)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:957:27)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:836:20)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:377:18)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:224:11)
      at ../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:135:36
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at ../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:133:65
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at JitCompiler._loadModules (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:130:71)
      at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:115:32)
      at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:69:33)
      at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../../../packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/compiler_factory.ts:69:27)
      at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../../../../packages/platform-browser-dynamic/testing/src/compiler_factory.ts:57:27)
      at TestBedViewEngine.compileComponents (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:362:27)
      at Function.TestBedViewEngine.compileComponents (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:160:66)
      at testing_1.async (src/app/app.component.spec.ts:11:8)

  ● AppComponent › should have as title 'frontend'

    Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).

      at syntaxError (../../../packages/compiler/src/util.ts:100:17)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:957:27)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:836:20)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:377:18)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:224:11)
      at ../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:135:36
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at ../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:133:65
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at JitCompiler._loadModules (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:130:71)
      at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:115:32)
      at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:65:38)
      at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (../../../packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/compiler_factory.ts:61:35)
      at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (../../../../packages/platform-browser-dynamic/testing/src/compiler_factory.ts:52:27)
      at TestBedViewEngine._initIfNeeded (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:376:28)
      at TestBedViewEngine.createComponent (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:570:10)
      at Function.TestBedViewEngine.createComponent (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:232:36)
      at it (src/app/app.component.spec.ts:21:29)

  ● AppComponent › should render title

    Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).

      at syntaxError (../../../packages/compiler/src/util.ts:100:17)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:957:27)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:836:20)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:377:18)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:224:11)
      at ../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:135:36
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at ../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:133:65
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at JitCompiler._loadModules (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:130:71)
      at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:115:32)
      at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:69:33)
      at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../../../packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/compiler_factory.ts:69:27)
      at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (../../../../packages/platform-browser-dynamic/testing/src/compiler_factory.ts:57:27)
      at TestBedViewEngine.compileComponents (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:362:27)
      at Function.TestBedViewEngine.compileComponents (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:160:66)
      at testing_1.async (src/app/app.component.spec.ts:11:8)

  ● AppComponent › should render title

    Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).

      at syntaxError (../../../packages/compiler/src/util.ts:100:17)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:957:27)
      at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:836:20)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:377:18)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (../../../packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts:224:11)
      at ../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:135:36
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at ../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:133:65
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at JitCompiler._loadModules (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:130:71)
      at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:115:32)
      at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (../../../packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts:65:38)
      at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (../../../packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/compiler_factory.ts:61:35)
      at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (../../../../packages/platform-browser-dynamic/testing/src/compiler_factory.ts:52:27)
      at TestBedViewEngine._initIfNeeded (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:376:28)
      at TestBedViewEngine.createComponent (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:570:10)
      at Function.TestBedViewEngine.createComponent (../../../../packages/core/testing/src/test_bed.ts:232:36)
      at it (src/app/app.component.spec.ts:27:29)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       3 failed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.682s, estimated 2s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The tests run just fine when using Jasmine + Karma. It seems like something went wrong with the dependency injection when using jest for testing.

You can find the repository here: https://github.com/flolude/stackoverflow-monorepo-angular-jest/commit/9a2d8cac0dfa25a5f6620f38238c3f577b2acb63 to try it yourself.

Comment: Try mocking your dependency instead of importing the exact same one. You also have the [testing implementation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpClientTestingModule) of that service.

Comment: Mocking wouldn't change anything, because I haven't created my own Service (the issue is caused by something else)... The `HttpClientTestingModule` doesn't work, either... The strange thing is that is works fine when I follow the same steps in a standard Karma-Jasmine testing environment

Comment: You can't say that mocking wouldn't change anything. That's the basics of unit testing. For all I know, you didn't import the HTTP module in your test, hence resulting in that error. By the way, it would be great if you could post your code, because we can't tell you what's wrong with it if we don't see it ...

Comment: (And no, I do not want to browse your github to find the code, and you're supposed to post your code on your question in case the external link doesn't work)

Comment: @Maryannah you are totally right! My fault. I've added the code snippets now :)

Comment: I am having the same problem, except with the Apollo client. Any resolution on this?

Comment: Not yet... I'll start a bounty tomorrow in case no one answers. And let me know when you found a fix :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just set the `emitDecoratorMetadata` to `true` in your `tsconfig.spec.json`.

This allows the `ts-jest` not to lose the metadata during the TypeScript transpilation. This issue came unexpected for `jest-preset-angular` developer after the Angular updated to version 8.1

Here's the issue on `jest-preset-angular` GitHub: https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/288

Comment: perfect. had exactly the same issue today and this solved it.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I had this set on the tsconfig.json file, which my tsconfig.spec.json inherited from, but I still had to set this option in the tsconfig.spec.json file. Thanks!

Comment: Also interesting: I had it only in the `tsconfig.spec.json` first and it had not effect, so I moved the property into `tsconfig.json` (from which tsconfig.spec.json inherits) and only then it worked. Kind of the opposite of what Matt experienced. Bottom Line: Before you give up, try all combinations :-)