# Can't run tests in a Angular 9 project

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular9, ts-jest

I'm working on an Angular codebase (first time) and I want to test my components using the default test runner brought with Angular. Here, my issue is that I can't run tests, I always get an error, the same for each test:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    File not found: jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer.js (resolved as: /path/to/project/client/jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer.js)

      at ConfigSet.resolvePath (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:725:19)
      at node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:250:98
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at ConfigSet.get (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:250:64)
      at ConfigSet.<anonymous> (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/util/memoize.js:44:24)
      at ConfigSet.get (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:315:41)
      at ConfigSet.<anonymous> (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/util/memoize.js:44:24)
      at ConfigSet.get (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:585:32)
      at ConfigSet.<anonymous> (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/util/memoize.js:44:24)
      at ConfigSet.get (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:603:25)
```

**note: in the original error "path/to/project" is the absolute path to the project and it is correct.**

As I said **every tests** returns the same error as above so the final output of `yarn test` is:

```
Test Suites: 48 failed, 48 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.896 s
Ran all test suites.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

My codebase uses Angular 9:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.12
Node: 10.23.2
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.1.12
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.10
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.10
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.10
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.12
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.12
@angular/cdk                      12.2.4
@angular/flex-layout              9.0.0-beta.31
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.10
@schematics/angular               9.1.12
@schematics/update                0.901.12
rxjs                              6.6.0
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

It also follows the basic jest-preset-angular config example (I think):

```js
// client/jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  roots: ['src'],
  coverageDirectory: 'reports',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setup-jest.ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@app/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/app/$1',
    '@env': '<rootDir>/src/environments/environment'
  },
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true,
      tsConfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json'
    }
  },
  // Do not ignore librairies such as ionic, ionic-native or bootstrap to transform them during unit testing.
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(jest-test|@clr))']
};
```

```
// client/src/setup-jest.ts
import 'jest-preset-angular';

/* global mocks for jsdom */
const storageMock = () => {
  let storage: { [key: string]: string } = {};
  return {
    getItem: (key: string) => (key in storage ? storage[key] : null),
    setItem: (key: string, value: string) => (storage[key] = value || ''),
    removeItem: (key: string) => delete storage[key],
    clear: () => (storage = {}),
  };
};

Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', { value: storageMock() });
Object.defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', { value: storageMock() });
Object.defineProperty(window, 'getComputedStyle', {
  value: () => ['-webkit-appearance'],
});

Object.defineProperty(document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    };
  },
});

Object.defineProperty(window, 'getComputedStyle', {
  value: () => ({
    getPropertyValue: (prop: any) => {
      return '';
    },
  }),
});

Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
  value: (query: any) => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null as any,
    addListener: () => {},
    removeListener: () => {},
  }),
});
```

And my package.json has the following versions of jest-related modules:

```json
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.2",
        "jest": "26",
        "jest-preset-angular": "^8.2.1",
        "@angular-builders/jest": "^8.3.2"
    }
}
```

As I said, I'm a beginner with Angular. As far as I can't understand, this error seems to come from a build error / transpilation error but I can't find any response to this problem. Has someone already experienced the same issue?

I've already tried the following things:

[Angular + Jest: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075111/angular-jest-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-appcomponent)

https://itnext.io/how-i-do-configure-jest-to-test-my-angular-8-project-2bd84a21d725

[Angular 8 and jest - File not found: jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58498885/angular-8-and-jest-file-not-found-jest-preset-angular-inlinehtmlstripstylestr)

https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular#exposed-configuration

## EDIT

I already tried [Angular 8 and jest - File not found: jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58498885/angular-8-and-jest-file-not-found-jest-preset-angular-inlinehtmlstripstylestr) . I changed my jest.config.js as following, and it still doesn't work. The same error is produced.

```js
// https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular#brief-explanation-of-config
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  roots: ['src'],
  coverageDirectory: 'reports',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setup-jest.ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@app/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/app/$1',
    '@env': '<rootDir>/src/environments/environment'
  },
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true,
      tsConfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      astTransformers: [
        "jest-preset-angular/build/InlineFilesTransformer",
        "jest-preset-angular/build/StripStylesTransformer"
      ]
    }
  },
  // Do not ignore librairies such as ionic, ionic-native or bootstrap to transform them during unit testing.
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(jest-test|@clr))']
};
```

## EDIT 2

I tried both syntax proposed by [Angular 8 and jest - File not found: jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58498885/angular-8-and-jest-file-not-found-jest-preset-angular-inlinehtmlstripstylestr) .

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/58499156/8902132)
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/68728271/8902132)

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  roots: ['src'],
  coverageDirectory: 'reports',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setup-jest.ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@app/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/app/$1',
    '@env': '<rootDir>/src/environments/environment'
  },
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true,
      tsConfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
      astTransformers: {
        before:[
          "jest-preset-angular/build/InlineFilesTransformer",
          "jest-preset-angular/build/StripStylesTransformer"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  // Do not ignore librairies such as ionic, ionic-native or bootstrap to transform them during unit testing.
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(jest-test|@clr))']
};
```

In both cases the test command output:

```
 FAIL  src/app/modules/hypervision/hypervision.service.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    File not found: jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer.js (resolved as: /path/to/project/client/jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer.js)

      at ConfigSet.resolvePath (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:725:19)
      at node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:250:98
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at ConfigSet.get (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:250:64)
      at ConfigSet.<anonymous> (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/util/memoize.js:44:24)
      at ConfigSet.get (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:315:41)
      at ConfigSet.<anonymous> (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/util/memoize.js:44:24)
      at ConfigSet.get (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:585:32)
      at ConfigSet.<anonymous> (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/util/memoize.js:44:24)
      at ConfigSet.get (node_modules/ts-jest/dist/config/config-set.js:603:25)
```

## Edit 3

I've abandonned the idea of using jest for testing my project. I've completly removed jest and installed karma.

Before installing karma, I've tried to re-install completly jest in my project, but even then it didn't work. In my opinion, the main reason for jest to not work is the mismatch between the version of `jest`, `jest-preset-angular`, `@angular-builders/jest`.

Comment: I would say this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58498885/angular-8-and-jest-file-not-found-jest-preset-angular-inlinehtmlstripstylestr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 8 and jest - File not found: jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58498885/angular-8-and-jest-file-not-found-jest-preset-angular-inlinehtmlstripstylestr)